# UIPanGestureRecognizer и touchesEnded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit, multi-touch

У меня есть сцена, на ней идет обработка нажатий через `touchesBegan` и `touchesEnded`. Обработка движения пальца по экрану идет через `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Все работает кроме одного момента: `Gesture Recognizer` не дает работать `touchesEnded` пока на есть косание экрана.

Пример 1:

1. Нажимаешь на экран -> срабатывает `touchesBegan 1`
2. Отпускаешь палец -> срабатывает `touchesEnded 1`

Пример 2:

1. Нажимаешь на экран -> срабатывает `touchesBegan 1`
2. Нажимаешь на экран вторым пальцем -> срабатывает `touchesBegan 2`
3. Отпускаешь палец -> ничего не происходит
4. Отпускаешь второй палец -> срабатывает `touchesEnded 1` и `touchesEnded 2`

В первом примере все отлично, но во втором примере в 3 пункте должен срабатывать `touchesEnded 1`, и если отключить `UIPanGestureRecognizer` он и срабатывает, но мне нужен `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Может кто знает как это побороть?

Comment: предположу, что надо поставить `isMultipleTouchEnabled = YES;` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622519-ismultipletouchenabled

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko в первую очередь это прописал, не помогло(